# WebDriver Javascript: How to get comprehensive DOM when the script is turned off on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML file:

```
<div id="test">Hello World</div>
<script>document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Test";</script>
```

Using Selenium Webdriver with Javascript Binding, I want to get a comprehensive DOM of the HTML file, such as list of attributes of an element, namespace of each attribute, namespace of the element, and so on.

I use the executeScript method to extract that because simply Selenium does not have that API yet, for example:

```
driver.executeScript("return document.lastChild.attributes.length;");
```

The problem is, I want to extract DOM of the HTML file while the script is being turned off. I turned off javascript on Chrome and still can execute the script from Selenium to get the DOM. But when it comes to Firefox, unfortunately I couldn't make it. The script is blocked and I got error message:

```
JavascriptError: waiting for evaluate.js load failed
```

I have tried to enable and disable the javascript by setting on the about:config or even having script blocker add ons like noscript and yesscript, but no luck. It seems like it is simply when the javascript is turned off on that page, Selenium cannot execute script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. It is ineffective anyway, but this is an alternative to execute the script from Selenium without using executeScript method. Calling the browser console, write the script, put the result into alert, then get the text from the alert. Here is the example:

```
var script = 'alert("value you want to get");';
var act = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver);
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('html')).sendKeys(Key.CONTROL + Key.SHIFT + 'k'); // Calling browser JS console
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Key.RETURN); // Switch focus to the console
act.sendKeys(script).sendKeys(Key.RETURN).perform(); // Write the script on the console
driver.switchTo().alert().getText().then(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
}); // Switch to and get the text from the alert
driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); // Close the alert box
```